# What do the stars next to the artes mean?

Tags: tales-of-arise

When I'm in the arte screen, there are 5 stars next to each arte, with a use counter and a threshold. When I reach the threshold, I get another star the next threshold starts.

What do these stars actually do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The in-game Field Guide is remarkably thin on the details of what using an Arte enough to level it up is, other than

> It'll become stronger

[image: EnhancingArtes]

My guess would that it increases it's damage and might also increase it's chance to interrupt an opponent (Penetration)

Comment: I wish I knew more about this game specifically, but don't have it yet... in the past Tales games, the arte levels also granted titles, and sometimes even unlocked additional artes/combo artes. However, I know this new game is different with learning artes, the proficiency gauge, etc. So, if there are additional benefits to leveling them up, I'm not sure. That field guide entry here is also... not the most helpful, hah.